# jQuery .hide and navigation through lightbox isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm dealing for nearly 3 hours with the lightbox script of: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/super-simple-lightbox-with-css-and-jquery--webdesign-3528   but dont not getting it running. the lightbox openes, but I cannot close it with the "x" in the upper corner or use the arrow at the left and right side. Can anybody help and see my mistake?

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var files = new Array();

    var i =0;
    $( "#test li" ).each(function() {
        files[i] = $("#test li" ).get(i).innerHTML;
        i++;
    });
    index = 0;
    $('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {
        //prevent default action (hyperlink)

        index = 0;
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get clicked link href
        var image_href = $(this).attr("href");
        /*  
        If the lightbox window HTML already exists in document, 
        change the img src to to match the href of whatever link was clicked

        If the lightbox window HTML doesn't exists, create it and insert it.
        (This will only happen the first time around)
        */

        if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) { // #lightbox exists
            //place href as img src value
            $('#content').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="left">Left</a>' +
                    '<iframe src="' + files[0] +'" />' +
                '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="right">Right</a>');

            //show lightbox window - you could use .show('fast') for a transition
            $('#lightbox').show();
        }
        else { //#lightbox does not exist - create and insert (runs 1st time only)

            //create HTML markup for lightbox window
            var lightbox = 
            '<div id="lightbox">' +
                '<p>x</p>' +
                '<div id="content">' + //insert clicked link's href into img src
                '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="left"><img src="http://musicum.eu/wp-content/themes/academy/images/left-arrow.png"></a>' +
                    '<iframe src="' + files[0] +'" />' +
                '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="right"><img src="http://musicum.eu/wp-content/themes/academy/images/right-arrow.png"></a>' + 
                '</div>' +  
            '</div>';
            //insert lightbox HTML into page
            $('body').append(lightbox);
        }

    });

    $('#left').click(function() { //must use live, as the lightbox element is inserted into the DOM
    //  alert("left");
        if(index>0)
        {   
            index--;
            $('#content').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="left"><img src="http://musicum.eu/wp-content/themes/academy/images/left-arrow.png"></a>' +
                    '<iframe src="' + files[index] +'" />' +
                '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="right"><img src="http://musicum.eu/wp-content/themes/academy/images/right-arrow.png"></a>');         
        }
        arrowShowHide(index);
    });
    $('#right').click(function() { //must use live, as the lightbox element is inserted into the DOM
    //  alert("right");
        if(index < files.length - 1)
        {
            index++;
            $('#content').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="left"><img src="http://musicum.eu/wp-content/themes/academy/images/left-arrow.png"></a>' +
                    '<iframe src="' + files[index] +'" />' +
                '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="right"><img src="http://musicum.eu/wp-content/themes/academy/images/right-arrow.png"></a>');
        }
        arrowShowHide(index);
    });

    function arrowShowHide(index)
    {
        if(index >= files.length -1)
            document.getElementById("right").style.display = "none";
        else
            document.getElementById("right").style.display = "block";

        if(index <= 0)
            document.getElementById("left").style.display = "none";
        else
            document.getElementById("left").style.display = "block";
    }

    //Click anywhere on the page to get rid of lightbox window
    $('p').click(function() { //must use live, as the lightbox element is inserted into the DOM
        //alert("right");
        $('#lightbox').hide();
    });

});


</script>
```

Thank you very very much.

Comment: can you provide your html code or jsfiddle if possible?

Comment: quite difficult because it's in a wordpress website. do you see any mistakes in that code for now?

Comment: you can copy html source code of the page from your browser also.

Comment: I can give you the URL of the website where that code need to be executed: http://bit.ly/1sBpx3O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set 100% width for your lightbox div, which is occupying full page width. Because of that click event on `<p>x</p>` cannot be triggered.

Reduce width of `#lightbox`, and replace following parts of code in your script,

```
        $("#backgroundPopup").show();
        if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) { // #lightbox exists
            //place href as img src value
```

And,

```
        $("#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
            $("#backgroundPopup").hide();
            $('#lightbox').hide();
        });
```

Then change css properties of `#lightbox`,

```
    #lightbox {
        position:fixed; /* keeps the lightbox window in the current viewport */
        top:0; 
        left:25%; 
        height:100%; 
        text-align:center;
        z-index:1;  
    }
```

Also, change opacity of `#backgroundPopup` to 0.8 or something.

Comment: thank you. I changed this but that doesnt make any difference. the width and height om 100% is just for the "darken" of the backgrund. Even when I decrese it to 1% it's not working :(  any other idea?

Comment: I've modified the ans. Try this again. Lightbox will be closed when  you click on darken overlay background. I haven't checked close button.

Comment: thank you. I tryed as you mentioned but without any change :(

Comment: Hmm.. It worked when I tried. After changing above code, lightbox was getting closed when clicked anywhere in the dark background.